# Shapes, Material You and Android Widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, shapes, material-you

I'm revamping my app's widget to follow the latest Material You guidelines, and i found many great inspirations looking at the screenshots from Google, like this one for example:

[image: Android 12 widget examples]

The main question is, are the shapes (for example, the circular image or the "polygonal" shape of the clock, which i also saw in other examples of totally different nature, like images) used in those screenshots easy to use? As far as i can tell following the Medium articles and guides from Google, the only easy effect to obtain are the rounded corners.

So, to be concise: is there an **easy** way to make an imageview circular and use shapes, or i simply have to obtain them manually and add this in programmatically?

Comment: if i had to suggest, `is there an easy way to...` is quite based on opinion, perhaps changing your question to focus on how to achieve one specific thing and showing what you've done will be better

Comment: I agree, but in this particular case, there's an old and unconvenient way to do this (which i already know) and a (maybe) new way, but i wasn't able to find it. I understand it is not a "classic" question, but the lack of sources and examples for this topic forced me to ask this way